# Removing labelling noise

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, semi-supervised-learning

I have a big data set with unlabelled observations (several million) and about 20 thousand properly labelled ones. There are only two classes and all correctly labelled samples belong to the same class. I want to see if I can expand my data set using the following technique:

First I construct my classifier using only these 20k samples from one class and another 20k from another (I have them too). Then I incrementally classify the unlabelled observations train the classifier on the dataset with the newly labelled data added in, and continue doing so until I exhaust the unlabelled data pool. Could you please comment on this? Would that be a valid strategy? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Why not just train your classifier on the known data (perhaps using cross validation to get a better sense of it's out of sample accuracy), & then use the trained model to predict the class membership of the unlabeled data?

Comment: You should read about methods for [Semi-supervised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning) learning.

Comment: @gung, fine, I sure can do that, but then would it make it sense to use it for training so that a have a bigger training set?

Comment: @alto Thanks! That's a helpful hint. Would you have some more links to suggest? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't see that it would. You have a tradeoff between higher N & greater measurement error in your new (larger) training set. I don't think the increase in N would outweigh the increased error.